# boost_signals library not found

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a Fedora 30 Workstation. I want to install ROS. Tutorial/Instructions link : http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source.

The Step 2.1.2 Building the catkin Workspace, when I execute the given command, It fails. There are 2 errors that I can see from the terminal output

1. Could not find the following Boost libraries: boost_signals
2. Failed to process package 'tf2'

For the 1st error, I checked the /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake file, It has a single line referring to the signals headers : set(_Boost_SIGNALS_HEADERS  "boost/signals2.hpp"). The file signals2.hpp exists in the boost directory, so that is not the issue. ROS, I guess, is not able to find this header file for some reason.
I have also installed all the boost libraries via dnf ( boost, boost-devel, boost-python3).

For the 2nd error, I have installed the geometry libraries via dnf, it doesn't solve the issue.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2165 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
  Boost version: 1.69.0
  Boost include path: /usr/include
  Could not find the following Boost libraries:
        boost_signals
  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'tf2': 
 Command '['/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2', 
'-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2', '- 
  DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/tf2 && /home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake 
/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2 - 
DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/tf2 - 
DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/devajji/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333142/boost_signals-library-not-found/) by [midas](https://answers.ros.org/users/45678/midas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-17**:
Can you please update your question with a link to the tutorial that you're referring to?

**Comment by [midas](https://answers.ros.org/users/45678/midas/) on 2019-09-17**:
Please check the updated link in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at https://github.com/ros/geometry2/pull/354, which removes the `signals` requirement. That change hasn't been released yet, but I'm pretty sure it addresses this error.

---

Originally posted by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) with karma: 311 on 2019-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [midas](https://answers.ros.org/users/45678/midas/) on 2019-09-17**:
Thank you! This worked.
Basically, all instances of signals had to be removed.
I also encountered a boost_python library not found - This was fixed by changing
this : find_package(Boost REQUIRED python) to this : find_package(Boost REQUIRED python27)
If it still fails, delete everything and do the recommended installation, instead of the full installation.

**Comment by [exoticdft](https://answers.ros.org/users/46192/exoticdft/) on 2019-09-25**:
This worked for me as well, with the geometry2 library. However, I'm running into the same issues in the ros_comm library (message_filters and roscpp CMakeLists.txt files) and geometry (tf CMakeLists.txt). In case anyone else runs into this before ROS releases the fixes. Also the python issue mentioned above is found in vision_opencv library (cv_bridge CMakeLists.txt).